# What is the recommended/correct way to access fields in an inner class?

Tags: java, inner-classes

Suppose we have this class and its inner class:

```
/* Outer.java */
public class Outer {
    private static class Inner {
        private final Object foo;

        public Inner(Object foo) {
            this.foo = foo;
        }

        public Object getFoo() {
            return foo;
        }
    }

    Inner inner = parse(/* someMistery */);

    // Question: to access foo, which is recommended?
    Object bar = inner.getFoo();
    Object baz = inner.foo;
}
```

I am surprised that `inner.foo` works.

Since `foo` is `private`, it can be accessed **only** through `getFoo()`, right?

Comment: java access rules are quit complicated (even more so for `protected`). but if it works, you should be happy, why complain:)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Since `foo` is private, it can be accessed only through `getFoo()`, right?

In this case, `Outer` has access to it too, because `Inner` is a member of `Outer`.

[6.6.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1) says:

> [If] the member or constructor is declared `private`, [then] access is permitted if and only if it occurs **within the body of the top level class** that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.

Note that it's specified to be accessible within the body of the *top level* class that encloses the declaration.

This means, for example:

```
class Outer {
    static class Foo {
        private Foo() {}
        private int i;
    }
    static class Bar {{
        // Bar has access to Foo's
        // private members too
        new Foo().i = 2;
    }}
}
```

Whether to use a getter or not is really a matter of taste. The important realization here is that outer classes have access to the private members of their nested classes.

As a recommendation, I would personally say:

- If the nested class is `private` (only the outer class has access to it), I wouldn't bother even giving it a getter unless the getter does a computation. It's arbitrary, and somebody else can come along and choose not to use it. If the styles are mixed, the code has a vagueness. (Do `inner.foo` and `inner.getFoo()` really do the same thing? We have to go waste time examining the `Inner` class to find out.)
- But you could go through a getter anyway if that's the style you are comfortable with.
- If the nested class isn't `private`, use the getter so the style is uniform.

If you really want to hide the `private` members, even from the outer class, you can use a factory with a local or anonymous class:

```
interface Nested {
    Object getFoo();
}

static Nested newNested(Object foo) {
    // NestedImpl has method scope,
    // so the outer class can't refer to it by name
    // e.g. even to cast to it
    class NestedImpl implements Nested {
        Object foo;

        NestedImpl(Object foo) {
            this.foo = foo;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getFoo() {
            return foo;
        }
    }

    return new NestedImpl(foo);
}
```

---

As a pedantic note, your `static class Inner {}` is technically a *static nested class*, not an *inner class*. `class Inner {}` (without `static`) would be an inner class.

This is [specifically defined](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.5.1) to be so:

> The `static` keyword may modify the declaration of a member type `C` within the body of a non-inner class or interface `T`. **Its effect is to declare that `C` is not an inner class.**

Comment: more pedantically, "static, member, class" :) Nested class includes more, like local class and anon class; though it is true that only a member class can be static

Comment: @bayou.io Yeah, if we're being specific. Since local classes and anonymous classes are always inner, all static nested classes are member classes.

Comment: Interestingly I would not understand that `Bar` is within the body of the toplevel class, but it works. (And Eclipse does not know it because it complains the private `i` is not used.). I guess "within" can be understood in different ways :)

Comment: @eckes Yep, it's a weird example. A "class body" is a [grammatical construct](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-ClassBody), which can contain other class bodies.

Comment: yes it can contain it, but I would expect "within body of top level class and nested all classes" (or similiar) in that case. "only within" is meh :)

Comment: @eckes Yeah, that's the JLS for ya. You need to read all of it to fully understand one part of it. Whenever I find an ambiguity like that, I tend to find a clarifying statement sometime later in some completely different section. One way we can infer my interpretation is, for example, by saying that if it were not the case, then a nested `class Foo`'s private members would not be accessible to itself.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your piece of code from where do you want to access that object. Since it is a static nested class, so you will be able to access your object from either ways. Refer to this link http://www.javatpoint.com/static-nested-class for better understanding of inner classes.